# Foreign Keys auto increment does not work in sqlite .NET provider

Tags: .net, sqlite, foreign-keys, connection-string, pragma

I insert multiple data into a sqlite table and get always the same ID back. But the field Id is configured as PK + autoinc Id.

I use this as connection string:

```
public static void SetConnectionString(string dataDataAccessPath)
        {
            _connectionString = String.Format(@"Data Source={0};Foreign Keys=ON", dataDataAccessPath);
        }
```

This "Foreign Keys=ON" was implemented for the connection besides the "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;" which had to be executed for every opened connection.

Now I wonder why the new attribute on the connectionstring does not work...

Do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on SQLite (in fact I have no practical experience with it) but I would imagine that whether or not your `IDENTITY` fields automatically increment with your insert has something to do more with the definition of the table than with the connection string you are using.

Be reminded that you cannot increment a `FOREIGN KEY` per se, but rather you need to increment the table with the `IDENTITY` field that serves as the `PRIMARY KEY` that the `FOREIGN KEY` then references.

Can you add the definition of the table that you are having trouble with?

Comment: this is just what I do. My table has an Id as PK + Autoincrement enabled. But for another table it works hm... I use 3.7.7.1. Hm... I am using TransactionScope instead of SQLIteTransaction and the Transaction + DbTransaction property of the SQLiteCommand object are NULL. Maybe there is a problem :/ gotta check that first using SQLiteTransaction.

Comment: If it works for another table then it should have nothing to do with your connection string (but shouldn't have anything to do with connection string anyway!). I would recommend that you post the SQL you used to create the working and non-working tables, as well as the code that actually performs the `INSERT`s that aren't incrementing your identity field.

Comment: stop! ;-) for the other table it did not work when I also did multiple inserts. I just faked another insert. Either the connection attribute is not working or its due to the TransactionScope. I check that out tomorrow see ya!

Comment: ok as I said I will do more tests. I found out the Foreign Keys connection attribute works ;-) by doing that I found the failure 20 inch before the screen :p I passed the commandInsert instead of the commandSelectLastAutoIncId somewhere... therefore I got bad results. Now everything works fine :)